# curve bunch of objects without joining them

Tags: mesh, bezier-curves

i made this mesh out of bunch of objects and i want to curve it using the circle curve and the curve modifier :

[image]

and i only know one way to do it, by joining all of the objects into one and curve it and after that i separate them one by one .
but when i join them i get this problem :

[image]

the ornament disappear and sometimes this happens :

[image]

i can't figure out why !!

is there a way to curve them all without having to join all of them like this :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select all objects with the one with the curve modifier selected as active.

Ctrl+L(link data menu)<modifiers(for pre 2.93)
(for 2.93)Ctrl+L<Copy modifiers.

Your geometry might be folding into other pieces because they don't have verts in the same sections. Match the loop cuts or give everything plenty of geometry

Comment: it worked thank you, i guess the problem was the bevel i applied to all of them

Comment: Great! Glad you found your asnwer!